# How are threads in GPU numbered?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

Suppose I declare threads and blocks like the following:

```
dim3 threads_per_block(2,2,2);
dim3 blocks_per_grid(2,2,2);
MyKernel<<<blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block>>>(... ... ...);
```

Are the threads and blocks in the grid numbered as follows?

If not, how?

[image]

1. Black = GPU
2. Blue  = grid**
3. Green = block
4. White = thread

** suppose the GPU has only one grid.

Therefore, if we want to obtain the (x, y, z) coordinate of thread #36, we can calculate it like the following:

```
int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x = 1 * 2 + 1 = 3
int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y = 0 * 2 + 0 = 0  
int z = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z = 0 * 2 + 0 = 0
```

Is it correct?

Comment: No this isn't correct. Threads are numbered within a block in order with the x dimension of `threadIdx` varying the fastest, then the y dimension varying the second fastest, then the z dimension varying the slowest. There is no thread numbering across blocks, that is completely at programmer discretion. I don't understand what the little triplets of brackets are supposed to be `[][][]` in each  cell in your diagram but there is not logical way I can see that would make them correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct?

The really short answer is no.

For this example:

```
dim3 threads_per_block(2,2,2);
dim3 blocks_per_grid(2,2,2);
MyKernel<<<blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block>>>(... ... ...);
```

You get something that looks like this:

[image]

Some salient points:

- threads are naturally numbered within a block with the x dimension of `threadIdx` varying the fastest, then the `y` dimension, then the `z` direction.
- blocks are naturally numbered within a block with the `x` dimension of `blockIdx` varying the fastest, then the `y` dimension, then the `z` direction.

That is the only numbering which exists in the standard CUDA execution model and which is exposed to the programmer. You are free to combine these in different ways to form numbering across dimensions or across blocks (for example as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)) but that is left to the programmer's discretion according to the characteristics of the problem you are solving, not anything intrinsic to the GPU or the layout of data in memory.

Answer (score -1):

Your vision is correct.

Taking into account your questions, I would highly recommend the book "Programming Massively Parallel Processors" by David B. Kirk and Wen-mei W. Hwu. It covers in details most of your topics.

Comment: I believe in both cases; I mentioned 2x2x2 sizes. All of them are pictured and calculated in 3D.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Misunderstood the picture.